# Are there javascript template engines that support something like recursion?

Tags: javascript, templates, recursion

The most obvious example I can think of is for outputting nested comments. Let's say you have a tree of comments and you want to output it as nested html (let's say lists inside lists or divs inside divs) using your template.

The "comment" block/function/tag/helper/whatever would have to be able to call itself somehow for the comment's children.

Are there template engines that would support that sort of thing inside one template file?

I am aware that you can just pre-compute the "indent" or "depth-level" of each comment and send them to the template as one flat list in the correct order, but let's just say I don't want that. And let's say I don't want to stitch snippets together in code / outside the template - I want the whole page self contained in one template or theme file.

---

**Update**: I want to generate nested html. I want the comments to *be* nested, not *appear* nested. I know how to indent things with CSS. :) Whether it is done in the browser or on the server is irrelevant because the point is I want the template to be self-contained in one file.

As in:

```
var html = render(template, {comments: aTreeOfNestedComments});
```

(see? that could be node.js, a brower plugin, some "jQuery" as some people like to call javascript these days...) It looks like jade can do this using mixins. Any tag-based templating engines that can do something similar?

Comment: Why Javascript? Cant you let the server create the output?

Comment: What do you mean by "Javascript template engine"?

Comment: @penartur: "template engine implemented in javascript". Just make it any template engine capable of outputting html, then.

Comment: @TJHeuvel: Well, would use it in node.js on the server and in the browser so you can see live previews. I guess javascript doesn't matter too much. Template languages that have different implementations - one of them being javascript - could also work.

Comment: For example, [jade](https://github.com/visionmedia/jade) allows one to define helper methods.

Comment: @penartur: (edited) nevermind. Looks like jade's mixins might do what I need. Any "designer-friendly" templating engines? (I already regret using that term..)

Comment: What do you mean by "designer-friendly"? Scripting ones (i.e. that allow you to write raw html with scripting PI added here and there)?

Comment: @penartur: Yeah something with tags you wrap around bits of html like a boring old "traditional" templating engine.

Comment: How about xslt then? It seems that there are xslt engines for node.js (though i'm not sure about the performance).

Comment: penartur: blegh. Thanks, but I think I'll keep looking ;)

Answer (score 1):

Template engines can solve generic, run-off-the-mill problems. While nesting templates seems like a common use case, I haven't encountered many template engines who can do that.

Since the market didn't offer a good solution, I'm building my applications from JavaScript objects that know how to render themselves. I never use templates; every block gets a reference to the DOM (like the parent element to which is should attach itself) or the renderers return the child container and the parent element can add that in a suitable place.

This allows me to use the full power of JS without the limitations of template engines.

**[EDIT]** Here is a workaround: If you need a recursive element, add a `span` (if the recursive element should be inline) or `div` (if it's a block element). Give it the class `recursiveTemplate` and a [data attribute](http://ejohn.org/blog/html-5-data-attributes/) `data-template-name="..."`

Run the template with your standard template engine. Afterwards, use jQuery or the like to find all elements with the class `recursiveTemplate` and replace them yourself.

Comment: I'm trying to make something designer-themable. Telling people to write DOM-manipulating JavaScript isn't really an option here.

Comment: In that case, define your own HTML element which allows you to say "insert another template here". See my edits.

Answer (score 1):

[Distal templates](http://code.google.com/p/distal/) has an example here of a nested tree:

http://code.google.com/p/distal/wiki/UseCaseExamples#Building_a_nested_tree

Answer (score -1):

as @TJHeuvel said, you can use the server side script to produce the desired otput, this would be the best way to do what you require. However if you must use JavaScript, I would advise jQuery this will also allow you to product the desired result.

for example:

```
$("ul li").css("margin-left", "10px");
```

Comment: I already addressed that in my original question: I specifically don't want that.

Comment: I was giving you an example of usage, you can however use recursive functions to apply a template to the entire tree and also make the tree items fully aware of the surrounding tree items, I do not feel this answer is out of the scope of the original question.

Comment: That's not even template code, that's CSS. And I don't want to write or apply a recursive function in the code. I was very specific about it. I want the recursion to be contained in the template.

Comment: so something like `$("ul li").addClass("myCoolStyle");`